# DICT object has no attribute 'Select_dtypes' Export Pandas DF to Google Sheets

Tags: pandas, pygsheets

I am having some trouble with Dict object has no attribute 'select_dtypes'

```
I have a dataframe that looks like the following.... 

     { 'miley cyrus' :{'top': query value
                                                          0           cyrus tours  100
                                                          1           cyrus update 8
                                                          2           miley and chris 6 }} 

When I attempt to export to Google Sheets, I get the error above. I have used this following code that worked fine up until now.  

Import pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file = 'mysecret.json'
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = related_queries 
sh = gc.open('Google Worksheet')
wks = sh[0]
wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))

I know the issue isn't connecting to GoogleSheets as I have connected to it in the past and exported DF with the code above .... there is something odd about the dataframe being in brackets {{ }} that I think is throwing off the code above. My question is how do i resolve this to print out the df like i have in the past.
```

Comment: I have researched dict.items too however, I am not sure where this argument would be located and what I need to remove from the original code

Comment: what is the error?